# eth-crypto: How can I use the library in the browser?

Tags: web3js

Has anyone manage to use eth-crypto in the browser? I tried to use browserify but I failed. Any hints, what to do?

EDIT:

This is what I did (node:10.15.1/npm:6.4.1)

1) Installed `eth-crypto` (v1.3.2)):

```
npm i eth-crypto
```

2) Created a file `main.js`:

```
var ethcrypto = require("eth-crypto");
```

3) Executed browserify

```
 browserify main.js -o eth-crypto.js
```

4) Include `eth-crypto.js` into my html.file:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='eth-crypto.js'></script>
```

5) After loding the file:

```
VM29:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: ethcrypto is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

`eth-crypto.js` has definitely been loaded as I can see it in the network panel of chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misunderstanding on how browserify works.
When you require a module, it will not be added to the window object. so window.ethcrpyto is undefined.

Comment: O.k. understood. But how can I access it. A hint would be appreciated very much :-)